# mysql_real_escape() w/ trim() w/ stripslashes() - is this sensible?

Tags: php, mysql

This might be a really stupid and self-answering question: I am stripping down my submissions like so (but need to submit to my table and also echo out the data to the screen):

```
$num_of_badges = stripslashes(trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['num_of_badges'])));
```

Of course the data is passed, but does the ``` stripslashes()``** here defeat the purpose of ```mysql_real_escape()`?

So: Bill's becomes Bills in the table and echo on the screen.

Comment: I am inserting this data by submission into a mysql table, so I am filtering the data before its INSERTed. Thanks for all the great advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need to submit to my table and also echo out the data to the screen

this statement is a key of all your problems.

while `trim()` and **conditional** `stripslashes()` are "submissions" related, mysql_real_escape_string is **completely different matter,**  it has nothing to do with submissions, input, output and all that stuff. It has relation to SQL queries only.

So, these functions should never be mixed.

- stripslashes should be conditional. **only** if magic quotes is on. can be checked with `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`. Applied to HTTP input variables only.
- trim is quite useless most of time but let it be, apply it to input.

these two above can be used blindly, at the top of your code. but third one,

- mysql_real_escape_string, as it's been said already, is **completely different matter.** It should be used on the **strings** that going to be inserted into query. Not on strings going to be echoed on screen. Not on numbers or identifiers, but strings (quoted blocks of data) going into query. So, mysql_real_escape_string can be used right before query building and nowhere else. And should be very last action done on your data before it goes to be inserted into query.

And also I hope you're not going to print your data right after inserting it into database. 
You rather have tho make a redirect, and then read your newly written data back from database.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and not mangle your data:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please use an example with enumerated parameters `->execute(array($name,$value))`. That's easier and makes people more willing to try PDO.

Comment: @mario, thanks, replaced with a different example stolen from the same page. I always liked how the other one showed off how easy it was to compile a query once for multiple executions, but if that looked like a hurdle, then by all means a different example should be given! :) Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the info. I am using this for a POST form, but I see how useful your note was.

Comment: @OldWest, don't let the `$_GET['blah']` fool you -- this is a generic technique that works on `GET`, `POST`, or variables that live their entire life in your program. :)

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer here is that stripslahes is in fact circumventing the mysql_real_escape_string.

```
$num_of_badges = trim(stripslashes($_Post['num_of_badges']));
$query_part = mysql_real_escape_string($_Post['num_of_badges']); // Or whatever...
```

Is probably how you're going to have to do it, remember you don't always have to be super concise. One line for one thing. :P